# Как выровнять текст с text-oveflow: ellipsis по правому краю?

Tags: html, css3

[image: Размер обрезанного текста 108px, а весь блок принимает размер 112px]

Имеется div на который навешаны стили `overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;white-space: nowrap;`
 После многоточия добавляется нежелательное пустое пространство в несколько пикселей, из-за чего не получается выровнять текст по правому краю. Размер текста `108px`, а блок с этим текстом `112px`, как переместить лишние `4px` в левую часть блока или обойти добавление лишних px? Большое спасибо.

Comment: Добавьте [минимальный воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 4):

Похоже это зависит от шрифта.
Попробуйте использовать `text-overflow: '..'`

```css
.overflow {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 200px;
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 200%;
}

.dot2 {
  text-overflow: '..';
}
.dot3 {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="overflow dot2">Какой-то длинный текст</div>
<br>
<div class="overflow dot3">Какой-то длинный текст</div>
```

---

Странно что в Google Chrome не работает "кастомный" `text-overflow`..
Тогда только "обрезать" при помощи `overflow: hidden;`.
Либо, если проблема всё таки связана с шрифтом, искать другой..

Comment: Кажется text-overflow: '..'; не работает. В вашем примере тоже.

Comment: в хроме работает!

Comment: @АлександрМанюнин, попробуйте не использовать IE (совсем) или обновить браузер.

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 получаю такой результат в хроме https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7jvO.jpg

Comment: @АлександрМанюнин, поправил ответ.

Comment: Фаерфокс работает